# Visa to Russia: tourist or business?

Tags: visas, russia, french-citizens

I am a French citizen going to Russia for a 6 day scientific conference. I have an official invitation letter (all in Russian) from the organizers, I have booked hotel and plane, and I am now looking at visa information… and it's driving me crazy! The sheer complexity of the system makes me imagine that it may be a scheme to drive unemployment down by hiring thousands of civil servants.

My specific question is: **what are the differences between a tourist and business visa?**

Business visas apparently allow longer stays, multiple entries, etc. Given that my stay will be short and simple (I come to Moscow, stay in Moscow, leave from Moscow), should I ask for a business visa or can I get a slightly less expensive tourist visa?

Comment: Welcome to Russian bureaucracy! :)

Comment: Yup. The joys.  Often it's easier to go through a company like visatorussia.com.  Last time I went as a tourist on a business visa - solely because I needed multiple entry and more than 30 days.  Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To visit a fair falls [under doing business](http://www.russianvisa.org/requirements.html), if it is part of your job, when being sent over by a foreign company. Specially if you want to do negotiations or even sign contracts. So you would need a business visa.

If the fair you are visiting is an industrial fair such as for machinery or trade, you will need a business visa.

However, there is conflicting information for this. [This russian company](http://www.saint-petersburg.com/russian-visa/frequently-asked-questions.asp) claims that as long as your trip fits into the time needed for a tourist visa, you can get one no matter what the purpose of your trip is.

I would recommend contacting your local Russian embassy or consulate and simply ask them.

Comment: It seems nothing is “simple” about visas for Russia. The consulate has outsourced its handling of visas to a private company, and they are not exactly easy to reach :(